# Java Regex - Invalid Escape Sequence w/ one backslash, Delete These Tokens w/ two

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I'm attempting to make a program to parse an output in Eclipse, but when I enter the regular expression like so:

```
Pattern signaturePattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z0-9_]+[" "]+[A-Za-z0-9\.]+[" "]+[A-Za-z0-9\.]+[" "]+[A-Za-z0-9\.]+[" "]+[A-Za-z0-9\.]+[" "]+");
```

The compiler gives me an error that says "invalid escape sequence." However, when I do what many answers to this question recommend - that is, to add an extra backslash to the dots - and I enter this instead:

```
Pattern signaturePattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z0-9_]+[" "]+[A-Za-z0-9\\.]+[" "]+[A-Za-z0-9\\.]+[" "]+[A-Za-z0-9\\.]+[" "]+[A-Za-z0-9\\.]+[" "]+");
```

The compiler instead says "Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens." How can I get it to simply read the regular expression as-is?

Comment: If you want to use `"` in your regex, you will need to use escape characters (`\"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to escape your double quotes, as such (one escape only): `\"`.

Here is your escaped `Pattern` (both code and `Pattern` compile, but I'm not guaranteeing it does what you want).

```
Pattern signaturePattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z0-9_]+[\" \"]+[A-Za-z0-9\\.]+[\" \"]+[A-Za-z0-9\\.]+[\" \"]+[A-Za-z0-9\\.]+[\" \"]+[A-Za-z0-9\\.]+[\" \"]+");
```

Comment: also "\." must escape the backslash

Comment: @gtgaxiola is I understand what you're saying, I think OP did that in the second `Pattern` they display in the question.

Comment: I, on the other hand, am pretty sure it *doesn't* do what you want.  (If it returns the desired result, it's only by accident.)  What are you trying to do with `[" "]`?  If you want it to match the literal string `" "`, you should drop the brackets (\" \"`).  If you're trying to match a space character, get rid of the quotes as well (leaving just the space character).

Comment: @AlanMoore yes, it's quite weird to have character classes containing two double quotes and a space. Yet again the scope here was to make it compile. I guess OP might want to post another question with desired I/O and this `Pattern` in case (when) it fails.